# Substitute text between specific strings

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to write a script to help me with a linguistics experiment. This experiment shows text phrases to subjects and they need to read the phrases word by word. For example, suppose I have the following phrase:

```
The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
```

I need to break this phrase into small parts, in order to show only these small parts to the subjects that will take the experiment. The software that shows the phrases to the subjects takes the following input:

```
The ---- --- ----- ---- --- ----------
--- girl --- ----- ---- --- ----------
--- ---- was ----- ---- --- ----------
--- ---- --- upset ---- --- ----------
--- ---- --- ----- with --- ----------
--- ---- --- ----- ---- her ----------
--- ---- --- ----- ---- --- boyfriend.
```

Notice that the complete phrase is never an input. I need to give the small parts to the software in order to it to show the phrases in the computer screen. Moreover, the words that do not appear in the screen must be changed for dashes, with the same length as the original word.

I was thinking to use one of those bash tools, like sed, grep, awk etc., to solve my problem. For example, I could write the original phrase as

```
The | girl | was | upset | with | her | boyfriend.
```

copy it seven times and, for each copy, use dashes for the words I do not need. Notice the words are always between two "|", making easy to identify them.

(in fact, sometimes I'll need to substitute more than words. For instance, I could have to substitute "The girl" all at once)

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: so if I understood you right, the 1st code block is input, and the 2nd code block(with dashes) is your expected output?

Comment: Yes @Kent, you are right.

Comment: ok, I post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see this awk one-liner, if it helps:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){t=$0;w=$i;gsub(/\S/,"-");$i=w;print;$0=t}}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
Yes @Kent, you are right. – grandeabobora 6 mins ago

kent$  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){t=$0;w=$i;gsub(/\S/,"-");$i=w;print;$0=t}}' f
The ---- --- ----- ---- --- ----------
--- girl --- ----- ---- --- ----------
--- ---- was ----- ---- --- ----------
--- ---- --- upset ---- --- ----------
--- ---- --- ----- with --- ----------
--- ---- --- ----- ---- her ----------
--- ---- --- ----- ---- --- boyfriend.
Yes ------ --- --- ------ - ------------- - ---- ---
--- @Kent, --- --- ------ - ------------- - ---- ---
--- ------ you --- ------ - ------------- - ---- ---
--- ------ --- are ------ - ------------- - ---- ---
--- ------ --- --- right. - ------------- - ---- ---
--- ------ --- --- ------ – ------------- - ---- ---
--- ------ --- --- ------ - grandeabobora - ---- ---
--- ------ --- --- ------ - ------------- 6 ---- ---
--- ------ --- --- ------ - ------------- - mins ---
--- ------ --- --- ------ - ------------- - ---- ago
```

Comment: Not really. I'm using a file called test.txt and I'm getting  

    '$ cat test.txt'
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    $ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){t=$0;w=$i;gsub(/\S/,"-",$0);$i=w;print;$0=t}}' test.txt
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.
    The girl was upset with her boyfriend.'

Comment: pls report your awk version @grandeabobora

Comment: Yes, it is. Does it matter if I'm running Mac OS 10.7.5?

Comment: try this `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){t=$0;w=$i;gsub(/[^ \t]/,"-");$i=w;print;$0=t}}' file` @grandeabobora, and report if it worked pls.

Comment: no problem @grandeabobora. your awk doesn't like (support) `\S`. :D.. mine is gnu awk 4.1.0.

Comment: Or more portably still `perl -ane '@s = map { $s = $_; $s =~ s/./-/g; $s } @F; for ($i=0; $i<=$#F; ++$i) { @t=@s; $t[$i] = $F[$i]; print (join (" ", @t), "\n") }'`

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

data='The girl was upset with her boyfriend.'
dashed="${data//[^ ]/-}"

IFS=' ' read -ra dataArray <<< "$data"
IFS=' ' read -ra dashedArray <<< "$dashed"
for ((i=0; i < ${#dataArray[@]}; i++)); do
    if ((i == 0)); then
        echo "${dataArray[i]} ${dashedArray[@]:i+1}"
    else
        echo "${dashedArray[@]:0:i} ${dataArray[i]} ${dashedArray[@]:i+1}"
    fi
done
```

#### More complex solution without if statement (You're the man if you can understand it!):

```
#!/bin/bash

data='The girl was upset with her boyfriend.'
dashed="${data//[^ ]/-}"

IFS=' ' read -ra dashedArray <<< "$dashed"
IFS=' ' read -ra dataArray <<< "$data"
size=${#dataArray[@]}
for ((i=0; i < size; i++)); do
    echo "${dashedArray[@]:0:i}${dashedArray[size-i]+ }${dataArray[i]} ${dashedArray[@]:i+1}"
done
```